# If statement for grid field type

Tags: grid

I have a grid field type that is working correctly without any issuse.  What i am trying to do is create an if statment basied on the search criteria of the grid search.

What I have:

```
<div class="twelve columns">
    {courses search:course_type="Foundation" search:degree_type="Masters" search:applies_to = "<?php echo $degreeName ?>"}
    <div class="more-button white course-list-title">
        {courses:course_number} {courses:course_title}
    </div>
    <div class="course-list-content">
        <p>{courses:course_content} </p>
    </div>
    {/courses}
</div>
```

The code above works fine.  What I want to do is create an if statment basied on the number of rows, that only returns one thing regardless if there are rows or not.

Something like this:

```
{if courses:total_rows > 0 search:course_type="Foundation" search:degree_type="Masters" search:applies_to = "<?php echo $degreeName ?>" }
    Some Code
{if:else}
    Some Other Code
{/if}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to separate the conditional from the variable pair, as they parse as two completely different entities in EE. There's no way to combine them into one tag.

However, this is fairly simple to do. Try something like this.

```
{if courses:total_rows > 0 }
    {courses search:course_type="Foundation" search:degree_type="Masters" search:applies_to = "<?php echo $degreeName ?>" }
        Some Code
    {/courses}
{if:else}
    Some Other Code
{/if}
```

Comment: I have tried that.  The problem is that the grid courses will always have rows in it.  I want to check if there are rows in there after I have applied my filters